# How to change jquery datatable language with variable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

How can I change my Datatable's language? This code is working but I want to change the language of `otable`. basically my issue is that when i change language than otable.columns() evnt is not working and when i use `var otable = $('#grdFormlist').DataTable();` than change language is not working

```
var otable = $('#grdFormlist').DataTable();

 otable.columns().every(function () {
                    var that = this;
                    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                            that
                                .search(this.value)
                                .draw();
                        }
                    });
                });

otable = $('#grdFormlist').DataTable({
  "language": {
    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
  }
});
```

Comment: `otable  !== oTable` (capital T)

Comment: man i want to change language by using this variable otable.language like something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks every one my issue solved by using timeout.

```
var otable = $('#grdFormlist').DataTable({
                    "language": {
                        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
                    }
                });
                setTimeout(function () {
                    otable.columns().every(function () {
                        var that = this;
                        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                                that
                                    .search(this.value)
                                    .draw();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },3000)
```